# node version issue in system

Tags: node.js, npm, system, nvm

I want to handle node versions using nvm. I have uninstalled node and started using nvm. but I'm getting the following issue shown in the screenprints. Couple of screenprints are added for reference.

**Any help would be appreciated.**

[image]

System variable setup is shown below

[image]

and this is where nvm is residing

[image]

Comment: Please check the values of `%NVM_HOME%` and `%NVM_SYMLINK` in your shell as well as where npm is actually installing node and include this information in your question

Comment: @Klaycon Not able to check those values from system - environment variables. please mention if there any commands to check their value from git bash.

Comment: `echo %NVM_HOME%`, `echo %NVM_SYMLINK%` in command prompt, or `echo $NVM_HOME` will probably work in your shell

Comment: @Klaycon tried with the last one and its showing **C:\Users\subho\AppData\Roaming\nvm**

Comment: @Klaycon and **echo $NVM_SYMLINK** is showing **C:\Program Files\nodejs**

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before as well. You can try removing both and installing from scratch with these commands .

```
rm -R ~/.npm ~/.nvm
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.1/install.sh | bash
nvm install node
```

Comment: Appreciating your try but its not working.. getting **error: unable to create file test/fast/Aliases/"nvm alias" should not accept aliases with slashes: Invalid argument** and **Failed to clone nvm repo. Please report this!**